# Jquery Conflict issue in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, slider

Sorry if my question is not good.

I am using this google library.

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

but it conflict to revolutions slider's jquery. When I remove this, revolution slider work properly but other sliders not work. When I add this other sliders work but revolution slider not work.

Comment: And why would you use that library, Wordpress has this built in, and uses `wp_enqueue_script` to make sure libraries like jQuery isn't included more than once, and that's why you should use it.

Comment: I use this lib for custom HTML slider, but now I convert that HTML in wordpress. So it already added when I create html.

Comment: Then you've built your custom slider the wrong way, the scripts needed for that custom slider should be added with `wp_enqueue_script`, whith jQuery as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the revolution slider plugin keeps a `min.js` with it!

So try removing the min file from its folder and check!

Comment: But when I remove min.js slider disappear